# Get assembly name at compile time and use it in code

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I want to get the assembly name at compile to add as a variable to a function.
Like c# has [Callermembername] as possible variable in code, I need a similar method to pass the assemblyname. The (eventually) called function must know the assembly name. Reflection can't be used.

I checked on MSDN to use the project setting, but I can't figure out how to use it in code.

Kind regards
Bram

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Get Assembly name at compile time in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1327719/464709).

Comment: Can you give us some idea about why Reflection can't be used? It seems like the ideal way to do this.

Comment: I can't use reflection because the calling hierarchy is not always the same, so I can't know for sure I'm at the right level of the stacktrace. 2nd reason is performance.

Comment: @Frederic, I saw the post and It's good to use the TargetName in pre and post build events. In fact, it would be exactly this property I want to reach from code.

Comment: @Bram, one possible solution would be to generate a `cs` file that exposes the assembly name as a constant during your pre-build step . You could then include that file in the project (it will be missing at first but everything will end up okay since it will be created when the build starts) and access the constant from the rest of the project.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggesting a cs file at compile time, as we also need other parameters. I do have an issue with using the T4 to get the assembly name, but I will raise a different issue for this.